# ES6 default parameters: values not assigned properly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

I'm playing with ES6 Default parameters, and I got a weird behaviour.

Here is an short example of the problem:

```
function test(firstValue, secondValue=5){
  console.log("firstValue: " + firstValue);
  console.log("secondValue: " + secondValue);
  console.log("----------")
}

test(2, secondValue = 3)
test(secondValue = 3)
```

And its output:

```
firstValue: 2
secondValue: 3
----------
firstValue: 3
secondValue: 5
----------
```

In the second case, I expected `firstValue: undefined` and `secondValue: 3`. Is this behaviour normal. Do I miss something?

Comment: secondValue = 3 is just regular assignment. really it's just test(3)

Comment: @Joe: With the side effect of creating an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(my blog post)*.

Comment: Default initialisers for parameters have nothing to with named arguments, which don't exist in JavaScript.

Comment: You want to combine default parameters with destructuring I guess, in your example you just created a method which requires 2 parameters and gave default values to them.

Answer (score 5):

When you do

```
test(2, secondValue = 3)
```

you are, in effect, doing this:

```
secondValue = 3
test(2, 3)
```

The first part (`secondValue = 3`) creates a global variable called `secondValue` thanks to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).* It has nothing to do with the `secondValue` parameter in your function. JavaScript doesn't have named arguments. (E.g., you can't say "here's the value for `secondValue`" when making a call except by putting it in the right position in the argument list. If you want to specify the names when making the call, you can use destructuring as [cubbuk points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42458580/157247), which isn't really named arguments but can serve the same sort of purpose.)

The second part (passing `3` into `test`) happens because the result of an assignment is the value that was assigned (so `secondValue = 3` sets `secondValue` to `3` and results in the value `3`, which is then passed into `test`).

To call `test` with `3` for `secondValue`, just do that. E.g.:

```
test(2, 3);
```

If you want to leave the second one off, the default will be used:

```
test(2);
```

Example:

```js
function test(firstValue, secondValue=5){
  console.log("firstValue: " + firstValue);
  console.log("secondValue: " + secondValue);
  console.log("----------");
}

test(2, 3);
test(2);
```

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: Thank you! Great answer, with detailed explanations, and a new blog to add to my favorites :) I'm from python, I've to switch my mind to think as a javascript developer. So, to achieve expected result, the best thing would be to pass an object as an argument?

Comment: @ErickHupin: :-) It depends on what your desired result is. If you want to name "arguments" when you make the call, then yes, you'd do `test({firstValue: 2, secondValue: 3})` and use destructuring as [shown by cubbuk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42458580/157247) (but see my note on that answer, it can be simpler). But if you just want default values, you'd do that as shown in this answer, without naming them when calling.

Comment: @ErickHupin: (cubbuk has updated his answer now, so I removed the comment I referred to above.)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a global variable without declaring it. The assignment generates a global variable and does not affect the variables of function `test`. These local variables are independent form the calling scope.

```js
function test(firstValue, secondValue=5){
  console.log("firstValue: " + firstValue);
  console.log("secondValue: " + secondValue);
  console.log("----------")
}

var secondValue; // with declaration
console.log(secondValue);
test(2, secondValue = 3)
test(secondValue = 3)
console.log(secondValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do destructuring I guess:

```js
function test({firstValue, secondValue = 5} = {}){
  console.log("firstValue: " + firstValue);
  console.log("secondValue: " + secondValue);
  console.log("----------")
}

test() // prints firstValue: undefined, secondValue: 5
test({}) // prints firstValue: undefined, secondValue: 5
test({firstValue: 2}) // prints firstValue: 2, secondValue: 5
test({secondValue: 3}) // prints firstValue: undefined, secondValue: 3
```

Comment: Good point, the OP might be looking for named arguments (as opposed to just confused about how to use defaults). If so, destructuring might be a way to go.